# How can i select text input in android avd command line?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I have to **QA** an inventory app that **contains a number of forms**. But I don't want to do monkey testing i.e fill the form each time etc. I want to **automate** that process. So i **auto select the field**(input) and past text to that field and then select next filed in the form. I know that we can pass the text to selected input via `adb shell input text 'your text goes here !!!'`

[image]

Comment: whats your question here? where are u stuck?

Answer (score 0):

[AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) simplifies the way you can create tests or scripts to achieve the automation you are looking for.

Most of the methods will eventually generate the same commands you send via `adb`.